# Ошибка подключения к базе данных PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

Windows 7, Visual Studio 2017, PostgreSQL 11, Python 3.6.

Пытаюсь сделать дамп базы данных:

```
args = ["C://Program files/Postgresql/11/bin/pg_dump.exe", "-d Test", "-U postgres", "-f C://Temp/Temp"]
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
data = process.communicate()
print(data)
```

Команда выполняется, запрашивает пароль, ввожу пароль выводит ошибку, на скриншоте.

Примечательно, что если из консоли вызывать эту команду, все происходит как надо, через `psycopg2` к базе подключаюсь тоже нормально.

[image: Ошибка в консоли]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
args = ["C://Program files/Postgresql/11/bin/psql.exe", "-d", "Test", "-U", "postgres"]
...
```

PS обратите внимание: `psql.exe` сообщил, что ему указали имя пользователя `" postgres"` (с пробелом в начале)

Comment: Да действительно пробел есть, но так как вы предлагает уже пробовал, выдает пустое окно, никаких ошибок, это при вызове psql. При вызове pg_dump в консоли появляется (b'', None) и все.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kg8P3Tw

Comment: @СергейНиколайчук, попробуйте для отладки указать пароль в аргументах `args`

Comment: Честно говоря гуглил как передать пароль через аргументы psql, ничего толкового не нашел, было через переменную среду, но я не понял как ее включить в args.

Comment: @СергейНиколайчук, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ma2cek

Comment: И насколько я понял, предложенный там метод chmod, это для Unix-подобных систем же.

Comment: pgpass также настраивал, и пароль вводить ненадо при попытке соединения через командную строку, но через subprocess все равно требует.

Comment: Все заработало, не понял честно говоря, что именно помогло, но после ребута все хорошо, спасибо в любом случае.